# How to start a fat jar in docker?

Tags: java, docker

I want to start my fat JAR inside a Docker container

Docker file

```
FROM java:8-jre
COPY config.yml /opt/hello/
COPY build/libs/Dockerwizard.jar /opt/hello/
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /opt/hello
CMD ["java", "-Xms128m", "-Xmx1500m", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-jar", "Dockerwizard.jar", "server", "config.yml"]
```

Everytime I run

```
docker build --tag=myapp .
```

and

```
docker run -p 18080:8080 -t -i myapp
```

I get the message

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile Dockerwizard.jar
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says:

```
COPY build/libs/Dockerwizard.jar /opt/hello/
...WORKDIR /opt/chat
```

So you are putting the Jar into `/opt/hello`, but then you want to run it from `/opt/chat`.

Maybe you want to look into using *consistent* path information. Beyond that, when you are not using the `-cp` option of java, you always have the issue that your CLASSPATH might be incomplete. So try adding `-cp .` for example.

Comment: Sorry there was an typo. On my part I messed up

Comment: No worries, cat. it takes some time so that I can accept your answer, but I will do it. Thanks for letting me off easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the WORKDIR in your Dockerfile

`WORKDIR /opt/chat` is incorrect

It should be `/opt/hello`

**Update**

you have updated the question and renamed `/chat` to `/hello` everywhere - so you have made a correction to your error/ mistake